# преобразование строки в список

Tags: python, строки, pandas, list

Имею данные на входе типа строки :

```
2020.12.03 04:45:53.399: Ask = 13277.5, Bid = 13275.0, Volume = 1, Last = 13275.0, Flag = 88, Volume Real = 1.0, Type = Sell, Spread = 25


2020.12.03 04:45:54.676: Ask = 13277.5, Bid = 13274.5, Volume = 1, Last = 13277.5, Flag = 56, Volume Real = 1.0, Type = Buy, Spread = 30


2020.12.03 04:45:55.922: Ask = 13277.0, Bid = 13274.5, Volume = 1, Last = 13277.0, Flag = 56, Volume Real = 1.0, Type = Buy, Spread = 25


2020.12.03 04:45:58.570: Ask = 13277.5, Bid = 13277.0, Volume = 1, Last = 13277.0, Flag = 88, Volume Real = 1.0, Type = Sell, Spread = 5


2020.12.03 04:45:59.73: Ask = 13277.5, Bid = 13277.0, Volume = 1, Last = 13277.5, Flag = 56, Volume Real = 1.0, Type = Buy, Spread = 5


2020.12.03 04:45:59.408: Ask = 13279.5, Bid = 13277.5, Volume = 1, Last = 13278.0, Flag = 120, Volume Real = 1.0, Type = N/A, Spread = 20


2020.12.03 04:46:00.840: Ask = 13279.0, Bid = 13277.5, Volume = 1, Last = 13277.5, Flag = 88, Volume Real = 1.0, Type = Sell, Spread = 15
```

Как привести входящие строки в список где `2020.12.03 04:45:59.408:` это дата, а все остальное

```
Ask = 13279.5, Bid = 13277.5, Volume = 1, Last = 13278.0, Flag = 120, Volume Real = 1.0, Type = N/A, Spread = 20
```

расходится по значениям где до `=` название и после `=` содержание.

Также имеется код(спасибо сообществу)

```
text = "2020.12.02 10:47:28.819: Ask = 13332.0, Bid = 13331.5, Volume = 2, Last = 13331.5, Flag = 88, Volume Real = 2.0, Type = Sell, Spread = 5"

res = dict()

pos = text.rfind(':')
res['time'] = text[:pos]

for data in text[pos + 1:].split(","):
    obj = data.split("=")
    res[obj[0]] = obj[1]

print(res)
```

однако у `res[obj[0]] = obj[1]` выходит ошибка

Comment: у меня все работает. какая именно ошибка?

Comment: у меня на выходе поступают данные из сокетов(выше пример)

Comment: мой код while True:
    data = client.recv(1024)
    text = data.decode('utf-8')
    print (text)
    #res = dict()
    #pos = text.rfind(':')
    #res['time'] = text[:pos]
    #for data in text[pos + 1:].split(","):
        #obj = data.split("=")
        #res[obj[0]] = obj[1]
        #print(obj)
        #print(res)

Comment: какую ошибку выводить?

Comment: list index out of range

Comment: Я слабо представляю, как вы хотите поместить данные в список. Может, вы имели в виду словарь?

Comment: да....скорей всего словать, извиняюсь, только изучаю....

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать регулярные выражения.

```
import re

lst = [
    '2020.12.03 04:45:53.399: Ask = 13277.5, Bid = 13275.0, Volume = 1, Last = 13275.0, Flag = 88, Volume Real = 1.0, Type = Sell, Spread = 25',
    '2020.12.03 04:45:54.676: Ask = 13277.5, Bid = 13274.5, Volume = 1, Last = 13277.5, Flag = 56, Volume Real = 1.0, Type = Buy, Spread = 30',
    '2020.12.03 04:45:55.922: Ask = 13277.0, Bid = 13274.5, Volume = 1, Last = 13277.0, Flag = 56, Volume Real = 1.0, Type = Buy, Spread = 25',
    '2020.12.03 04:45:58.570: Ask = 13277.5, Bid = 13277.0, Volume = 1, Last = 13277.0, Flag = 88, Volume Real = 1.0, Type = Sell, Spread = 5',
    '2020.12.03 04:45:59.73: Ask = 13277.5, Bid = 13277.0, Volume = 1, Last = 13277.5, Flag = 56, Volume Real = 1.0, Type = Buy, Spread = 5',
    '2020.12.03 04:45:59.408: Ask = 13279.5, Bid = 13277.5, Volume = 1, Last = 13278.0, Flag = 120, Volume Real = 1.0, Type = N/A, Spread = 20',
    '2020.12.03 04:46:00.840: Ask = 13279.0, Bid = 13277.5, Volume = 1, Last = 13277.5, Flag = 88, Volume Real = 1.0, Type = Sell, Spread = 15'
]

rex_time = re.compile(r'\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.?\d*')
rex_value = re.compile(r'\b(\w+)\b = (\d+.?\d*)')

for item in lst:
    res = dict()
    res['time'] = rex_time.search(item).group(0)
    for k, v in rex_value.findall(item):
        res[k] = v

    print(res)
```

Результат:

```
{'time': '2020.12.03 04:45:53.399', 'Ask': '13277.5', 'Bid': '13275.0', 'Volume': '1,', 'Last': '13275.0', 'Flag': '88,', 'Real': '1.0', 'Spread': '25'}
{'time': '2020.12.03 04:45:54.676', 'Ask': '13277.5', 'Bid': '13274.5', 'Volume': '1,', 'Last': '13277.5', 'Flag': '56,', 'Real': '1.0', 'Spread': '30'}
{'time': '2020.12.03 04:45:55.922', 'Ask': '13277.0', 'Bid': '13274.5', 'Volume': '1,', 'Last': '13277.0', 'Flag': '56,', 'Real': '1.0', 'Spread': '25'}
{'time': '2020.12.03 04:45:58.570', 'Ask': '13277.5', 'Bid': '13277.0', 'Volume': '1,', 'Last': '13277.0', 'Flag': '88,', 'Real': '1.0', 'Spread': '5'}
{'time': '2020.12.03 04:45:59.73', 'Ask': '13277.5', 'Bid': '13277.0', 'Volume': '1,', 'Last': '13277.5', 'Flag': '56,', 'Real': '1.0', 'Spread': '5'}
{'time': '2020.12.03 04:45:59.408', 'Ask': '13279.5', 'Bid': '13277.5', 'Volume': '1,', 'Last': '13278.0', 'Flag': '120,', 'Real': '1.0', 'Spread': '20'}
{'time': '2020.12.03 04:46:00.840', 'Ask': '13279.0', 'Bid': '13277.5', 'Volume': '1,', 'Last': '13277.5', 'Flag': '88,', 'Real': '1.0', 'Spread': '15'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать без регулярок, чтобы получить словарь типа {время:[значения]}:

```
text = "2020.12.02 10:47:28.819: Ask = 13332.0, Bid = 13331.5, Volume = 2, Last = 13331.5, Flag = 88, Volume Real = 2.0, Type = Sell, Spread = 5"

res = {}

def parse(a: str) -> dict:
    key, vals = a.rsplit(":", 1)
    val = [x.strip() for x in vals.split(",")]
    res.update({key:val})
    
parse(text)
```

тогда res будет:

```
{'2020.12.02 10:47:28.819': ['Ask = 13332.0', 'Bid = 13331.5', 'Volume = 2', 'Last = 13331.5', 'Flag = 88', 'Volume Real = 2.0', 'Type = Sell', 'Spread = 5']}
```